# Golang server background notofication process

Tags: mongodb, go, notifications, background-process, httpserver

I apologize in advance for my bad english.

I've created simple training service in golang, which supports login and registration system with MongoDB. This service allows you to scrape rooms for rent in London in specified location if you loggedin. So, now I want to implement notifications for loggedin user's about new rooms in user's marked location. My first idea was to make some background process, which will scrape rooms every 30 seconds, save the results *(in mongo, in cookies or somewhere else, advise me please)*, match new scrape results with previous and save differences (new rooms) in DB for future posting to user in some form (email or list on html page).

1) Is my idea about notifications generally correct? If not, please describe me better way to do this or point to some relating examples.

2) What is the best way to make that background process in go?

3) This would be great if you'd point me on some examples relating to the case.

---

[The demo of service on Heroku](https://spareroomgolang.herokuapp.com)

[Github repo](https://github.com/Jopoleon/spareroomscraper)

I appreciate your concern.

Comment: You can use goroutines to spawn of background jobs every X interval (a `select` on a Timer will help).

Comment: @Nadh Can you be more specific, please? If you want, I can add link to my demoversion on Heroku and to github repo.